# Is it possible to transform a settings table with unique names into a json hash object in postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a settings table with two columns - name and value. Names are unique. I can easily read it into memory and then create a dictionary using the entry names as the keys.

I was wondering whether this can be done entirely from the SQL using some postgresql functions and applying the `row_to_json` function at the end.

I have version 9.2

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible?  It should be.

I think what you'd have to do is create a function for pulling a record in (as an argument) and transforming it to a record of arbitrary type and turning that into JSON.

This was done on 9.1 with the json extension.

```
create or replace function to_json(test) returns json language plpgsql
as $$
declare t_row record;
        retval json;
begin
    EXECUTE $E$ SELECT $1 AS $E$ || quote_ident($1.name) INTO t_row 
    USING $1.value;
    RETURN row_to_json(t_row);
end;
$$;
```

Then I can:

```
select * from test;
 name  | value  
-------+--------
 test1 | foo
 test2 | foobar
(2 rows)

SELECT to_json(test) from test;
      to_json       
--------------------
 {"test1":"foo"}
 {"test2":"foobar"}
```

Now if you want to merge these all into one object you have a little more work to do but it could be done using the same basic tools.

Answer (score -1):

This *should* work in postgres-9.3. (untested, since I don't have 9.3 available here yet)

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE table pipo (name varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                , value varchar);

INSERT INTO pipo (name, value ) VALUES
('memory' , '10Mb'), ('disk' , '1Gb'), ('video' , '10Mpix/sec'), ('sound' , '100dB');

SELECT row_to_json( ROW(p.name,p.value) )
FROM pipo p ;
```

Comment: Nope, this is what you get on 9.2:
"{"f1":"memory","f2":"10Mb"}"
"{"f1":"disk","f2":"1Gb"}"
"{"f1":"video","f2":"10Mpix/sec"}"
"{"f1":"sound","f2":"100dB"}" whereas I am looking for {memory: "10Mb"}, ...